# How long would it take to learn c# if I know c++?

Tags: c++, c#

I already know c++, having worked through Accelerated C++ reading all the chapters and doing all the problems, with a bit of college coursework in C++ as well.

From what I read, I seem to have learned the harder of the two languages first.  My question is, how fast could I pick up C#?  I'm looking for a job and an awful lot of companies want experience with .Net framework and/or C#.

Are we talking another few months, or could I reasonably start programming in C# within a week?  I've got experience picking up new languages quickly, and I'm familiar with C, a little Java, Haskell, and Prolog.

Comment: Not sure a real answer can be provided.  Being a C++ guy, C# took me less than half a day to become productive, and a few weeks to become an expert on the intricacies that rarely even come up.  C# is easy to learn if you already know any language, especially in the C/C++/Java family.

Comment: Since there's no real answer to the question, I'm voting to close it as not constructive. It's a question you can answer for yourself in a week. It'll likely be easy enough for you to pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be more suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) I guess, but basically it's just some added knowledge, based on what you're supposed to do (like GUI programming in Windows Forms or WPF. Overall, I'd say you should be able to get the required basics in a few hours, especially if you've worked with STL classes such as `std::string` in the past. There are some added concepts and language constructs (especially if you plan on using LINQ as well), but overall I'd say you should be able to understand and train most generic concepts in a few weeks or just a few days (depending on how fast you learn, what you learn, etc.). Getting some simple UI program to run should be doable within a few hours though.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, like Sean and I did since it doesn't add much more information than that and doesn't actually answer "How long" (since that's not really answerable).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I understand it may have been better suited for another forum but thank you.